# Can I use my Yamaha i455 Keyboard as an external speaker?

Tags: keyboard, midi, speakers

I just got a Yamaha i455 keyboard. It has good speakers and I would like to use them as external speakers. The USB to host port works fine. I can't figure it out, but Synthesia plays the notes on my keyboard, so sound can be transferred from the computer to the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug in your keyboard.

Find some speaker settings on your PC. I know for macs, there's a program called 'Audio Midi Setup' where you can select the keyboard as your choice of speaker.

There should be something similar on windows - if that's what you're using.

Comment: using the USB to Host or AUX Cable? How do I do it?

Comment: I use a MacBook

Comment: I think its the usb to host. then go into launchpad, and find audio midi setup under 'other'

Comment: Then what should I do?

Comment: Well when I did it, the keyboard came up as an option as an output device and I just set that as my default. It was fairly self-explanatory although we've got different keyboards and it was on an older OS.